# Bitcoin C# .NET API

Tags: transactions, bitcoind

I am trying to get the address the bitcoins were last owned by or the "from" address, I know that if you send bitcoins back to that address not in all cases will the user actually get them but I still need the code for it. Thanks in advance.

I am thinking it has something to do with Program.b.GetTransaction()

If I have an address, and coins are sent to that address, I want to find out the address the coins were sent from, I have a different address for every transactions specially for this.

Comment: You could just make straight calls to bitcoind, from within a C# app.  Take a look at this question(http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/7369/how-to-implement-a-game-like-satoshidice/14073#14073).  The question is about Satoshi Dice, but it does provide instructions on how to get customer information, including their original payment address.  I'm not aware of a C# client.  However, a C# application could easily integrate with the bitcoind.exe console application.

Comment: I maintain a c# wallet client located on Github: https://github.com/chriswill/WalletClient.  The apis may help you.

Comment: Please look at the date, I have done C# and PHP implementations of that already...

Answer (score 1):

This is implemented in the `GetTransactionSenderAddress()` method of [BitcoinLib](https://github.com/GeorgeKimionis/BitcoinLib)