# Sender address from DecodeRawTransaction (C#)

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get the senders address using the Bitcoin JSON RPC in C#. So I GetRawTransaction and then use the DecodeRawTransaction method to return my JSON object. I can see in the 'vout' of this the receiver addresses but I cannot see the sender addresses in the 'vin'.

Can anyone help? I may have phrased the question poorly so please ask if you need any more informations. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The quote below is taken from my answer to [How to implement a game like SatoshiDice?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/14073/16)  What you are looking for is addressed in this portion of my answer below.

> **Get the customer amount and payment address**
>
> 1. Call `bitcoind getrawtransaction [The incoming transaction ID] 1`.  The 1 at the end will return the data in "verbose mode", which
>      essentially the raw data in JSON format.
> 2. From the raw transaction details, take the `txid` and `vout` from the `vin` object.  With this transaction, again call `bitcoind
>      getrawtransaction` on the `txid`.
> 3. From these raw transaction details find the `vout` object, referenced by the `vout` index from step #2.  Within this `vout`
>      object, there should be a list of payment recipient addresses.  Take
>      and store the first address.

It is worth mentioning that a received payment can be a summation of numerous, former transactions to multiple recipient addresses.  Getting an originators address isn't always straight-forward because the original payment could consist of multiple payments, from multiple sending addresses.

This is why that in my response to the SatoshiDice question I mention taking the first address from the second `vout` result.

You can safely assume that if someone sends you a payment originating from multiple accounts, they control all accounts. Ergo, picking the first in the list will give you correct address.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**BitcoinLib**](https://github.com/GeorgeKimionis/BitcoinLib)'s [GetTransactionSenderAddress](https://github.com/GeorgeKimionis/BitcoinLib/blob/master/src/BitcoinLib/Services/RpcServices/RpcExtenderService/RpcExtenderService.cs#L160) method, however it is important that you understand that this is a hack, as bitcoin's protocol doesn't support a "sender's address", and will only work for fat clients such as bitcoin-core etc.